# PowerShell Set Mandatory Property Based on Condition

Tags: powershell

I need to prompt a user to enter the full path of an executable *only* if it cannot be found in the system `PATH`.

I have a parameter block like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$oc_cli,
)
```

This determines if the executable exists in `PATH`:

```
$oc_in_path = [bool] (Get-Command "oc.exe" -ErrorAction Ignore)
```

I want to set the `$oc_cli` parameter as mandatory *only* if `$oc_in_path` is `FALSE`.

I have tried

```
$oc_in_path = [bool] (Get-Command "oc.exe" -ErrorAction Ignore)
function example-function {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$oc_in_path)] [string]$oc_cli,
    )
    Write-Host "Do stuff"
}

example-function
```

which throws error `Attribute argument must be a constant or a script block`

I have also tried

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    if (! ( [bool] (Get-Command "oc.exe" -ErrorAction Ignore) )) {
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$oc_cli
    }
)
```

How can I set the `Mandatory` property based on a condition?

Comment: Clever. I don't kow if it will work, but if it's asking for a script block, give it one. Wrap like: `$oc_in_path = { [bool] (Get-Command "oc.exe" -ErrorAction Ignore) }` . That will make `$oci_in_path` a script block.  More to follow...

Comment: just FYI ... the `Mandatory` you are speaking of is not a `property` of the parameter, it is an `attribute` of the parameter. i was quite confused when reading thru your Question. [*grin*] >>> `In Windows PowerShell 2.0, a new parameter attribute is introduced. This parameter attribute uses the Parameter keyword, and sets the Mandatory attribute to $true.` <<< that is from here >>> Use PowerShell to Make Mandatory Parameters | Scripting Blog — https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-make-mandatory-parameters/

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Unfortunately, the terminology you're citing is confusing. Technically, `Mandatory` is a _property_ of the [`Parameter` _attribute_ class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute), instances of which are used to decorate PowerShell parameter declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, which relies on being able to specify default parameter values via arbitrary commands, using `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--):

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [Parameter()] # in the absence of property values, this is optional.
  [string] $oc_cli = $(
    if ($cmd = Get-Command -ea Ignore oc.exe) { # oc.exe found in $env:PATH
      $cmd.Path
    } else { # prompt user for the location of oc.exe
      do { 
        $userInput = Read-Host 'Specify the path of executable ''oc.exe''' 
      } until ($cmd = (Get-Command -ea Ignore $userInput))
      $cmd.Path 
    } 
  )
)

"`$oc_cli: [$oc_cli]"
```

Note:

- The `Mandatory` property of the [`Parameter` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute) is *not* used, as it would - in the absence of an argument being passed - *unconditionally* prompt for an argument (parameter value).
- The above would still accept a potentially non-existent `$oc_cli` argument *if passed explicitly*; you could use a [`ValidateScript` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) to prevent hat.